# Disable future dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, html5-video, jquerydatetimepicker

My View:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" id="datepicker" ng-model="datepicker" name="datepicker" style="width:100%" tabindex="4"  required/>`  
Controller:  
  `$('#datepicker').datepicker({
 format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
 endDate: '+0d',
 autoclose: true
 });
```

> it's showing `TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`

I want to disable all the future dates after today
Trying to implement.

Comment: Did you include it into your page ?

Comment: yeah maybe the datepicker is not include in your page

Answer (score 1):

as others have mentioned you might have not included it in your page...and as far as logic concerned for disabling dates after today:

You can assign today to maxDate option of datepicker,

this is what jquery datepicker api docs have about maxDate option

> The maximum selectable date. When set to null, there is no maximum.

```
$(function(){

  $('#thedate').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      maxDate: new Date()
  });

});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myke_11J/t96dasou/) hope your issue is resolved now

Answer (score 0):

Use maxDate instead of endDate

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" id="datepicker" ng-model="datepicker" name="datepicker" style="width:100%" tabindex="4"  required/>`  

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
 format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
maxDate: new Date(),
 autoclose: true
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/ZL2Bc/2101/)

Answer (score 0):

```
data-plugin-datepicker data-plugin-options='{"autoclose": true, , "endDate": "0d", "format": "dd-mm-yyyy"}'
```

try this in html